# Connector for driver's side seat belt cable in KIA Soul

Tags: electrical, kia, soul

**Make:** KIA
**Model:** Soul+
**Year:** 2012

There is a cable that runs from the dash, under the seat, to the driver's side seat belt buckle. Underneath the seat, there is an obscure wire-to-wire molex connector that breaks the cable. Does anyone know where I can find a replacement connector for this? I have looked everywhere on-line and been unable to find one.

If we find that my description is not detailed enough, I will try to post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the connector to the buckle sensor, and you can call the dealer. Connectors and things like that are usually fairly affordable.